# How to display a loading template in Ember while model is being loaded?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, ember-cli

I want to render an loading template in Ember before the next template has loaded. Right now I have a loading template for the application route, and that works fine if the user navigates directly to the URL. However, I want that same template to be displayed if the user clicks a `link-to` to the page from within another page of the app. How can this be done?

Scheduling `afterRender` doesn't work because the page hasn't "loaded" yet (right now it just sits at the previous page for a couple of seconds as the next page loads; using afterRender causes the same thing, however once it loads you get a brief glimpse of the loading div before it fades out: clearly not the intended behavior).

How can I show the loading template instead?

Reducing the load time is not an option, we do some pretty heavy computations.

*EDIT*: I do believe that my question is different from the one suggested as duplicate because I want to have the same loading template for all routes, which the default loading template structure doesn't provide. The "legacy" LoadingRoute solution cannot work anymore as Views are deprecated with the newest version of Ember.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emberjs : how to display loading spinner and notification messages on model operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687215/emberjs-how-to-display-loading-spinner-and-notification-messages-on-model-oper)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding, [Ember.js loading substates](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-loading-code-substates) is exactly what you need, especially this part of the guide:

**app/router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo', function() {
    this.route('bar', function() {
      this.route('slow-model');
    });
  });
});
```

Ember will alternate trying to find a routeName-loading or loading template in the hierarchy starting with the first template:

- **foo.bar.slow-model-loading**
- **foo.bar.loading** or **foo.bar-loading**
- **foo.loading** or **foo-loading**
- **loading** or **application-loading** (which you already implemented)

I suggest that you remove the afterRender() as I do not know if it can interfere with firing the loading events. If the guides do not offer the solution, can you post a jsfiddle? Ember.js can get finicky depending on how you implement the outlets...

You can fork an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Deovandski/7sgkd1j0/) that I created for another question to quickly setup your JSFiddle to work with Ember.js

Comment: The issue is that I want to use the same loading template for all routes. Sure, I could copy the one and make it into a bunch of different files, but that seems inelegant, I feel like there must be a way to do it programmatically.

Comment: Ok so I have indeed implemented an Application-level loading route however I observe that it is not shown in between routes in the application, only on a full refresh. I infer that the template isn't "bubbling up" properly, and is only being shown on Application-level loading events.

Comment: This question is also trying to find out why it is not bubbling up (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889107/ember-loading-template-works-only-on-page-refresh)

Comment: You can also infer to issue #13267 opened on Ember.js Github. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12367 If those resources do not help you, then share your router routes or create a JSFiddle.

Comment: Yes, that SO link you posted is exactly the question I have. How do I use the same loading template for every route without duplicating the same file n times so that Ember finds them in the standard paths? Is there really no way to do it programmatically? Disappointing.

Comment: This is especially inconvenient for me because my project uses a flat folder for the templates (via specifying the templates explicitly) so I'd have to do some refactoring to reorganize in the way Ember wants

Comment: That is why Ember.js favors CoC and the DRY principle. If you feel like Ember.js framework is way too opinionated , then you should give Angular.js a try.

Comment: It does, but generally (as with the templates for example) it's CoC *however if you want to customize you can* type of thing. Like CoC first but more control if needed. I don't understand why loading templates don't subscribe to this general structure in Ember. A little too "magical" for me (nothing in Ember up to this point really has been for me).